# Python does not throw an error when using a wrapper

Tags: python, wrapper

```
def try_catch(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            res = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return res
        except:
            Print_Error()
    return wrapper
```

When using the try except construct with the Print_Error() function in the function itself, everything works, but when it is written in this construct and you apply @try_catch before the function, in case of an error, the function simply hangs

Comment: Please show example(s) of how you are attempting to use `try_catch`.

Comment: What is `Print_Error()`?

Comment: it works, just checked with a normal `print` instead of `Print_Error()`